# How to get default value of element using placeholder in Protractor?

Tags: angular, selenium, protractor

How to get the default text present inside the input in angular.

```html
<input _ngcontent-c20="" 
autocomplete="off" type="text" disabled="true" 
placeholder="Username" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
```

Default value present inside the text box is say "abc".

How to get this value, using `getText()` gives blank value.

PS : We need the verify the default text present inside the these inputs.

Comment: Could you please provide the screenshot of that input UI element

Answer (score 1):

Try the below one

```
ele = element(by.css('input[placeholder="Username"]'));

ele.getAttribute('value');  //This gets the input field value
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: @Rahul Do mark the answer correct so that it helps others with the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using this :

```
document.querySelector('[placeholder="placeholder name"]')
```

Try following :

HTML :

```
<p>Click the button to get the value using placeholder of the text field.</p>

<input _ngcontent-c20="" 
autocomplete="off" type="text" disabled="true" value="abc"
placeholder="Username" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">

<button onclick="getText()">Try it</button>

<script>
    function getText() {
        var usernameInputElement = document.querySelector('[placeholder="Username"]')
        console.log(usernameInputElement.value); // Current input value
    }
</script>
```

`console.log(usernameInputElement.value)` will print out the input value.

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript Executor, you will get the 'value' which is the default attribute for input elements.

following function will return the result.

```
async function getAttributeValueWithJS(attributeName: string, element: ElementFinder) {
    await browser.executeScript(`return arguments[0].getAttribute('${attributeName}')`, element);
}

const el = element(by.css('input[placeholder="Username"]'));
const defValue = await getAttributeValueWithJS('value', el);
```

Comment: There is ready-to-use method getAttribute('value'). No need to overcomplicate

Comment: Default getAttribute func, which comes from selenium impl its not the same as using javascript executor.
You could get empty string if the value is kept in different element property inside the HTMLelement